# Loop through Array, with Similar items First in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [intID] => 3
        [intVolumeType] => 1
        [intVolume] => 10
        [totalVolumes] => 10
        [intTrack] => 10
        [intTrackType] => 2
        [totalTracks] => 10
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [intID] => 4
        [intVolumeType] => 2
        [intVolume] => 100
        [totalVolumes] => 200
        [intTrack] => 111
        [intTrackType] => 3
        [totalTracks] => 222
    )
```

)

I want to print above array as:
intVolumeType = 1
totalVolumes  = 10
intVolumeType = 2
totalVolumes  = 200

---

intTrackType  = 2
totalTracks   = 10
intTrackType  = 3
totalTracks   = 222

How to loop through this PHP array. There are total six elements in array. Which might increase upto 20. Print first Volume Information, than Track, and so on.Please help

Answer (score 0):

try this here: http://phpfiddle.org/

```
<?php
$a = Array
    (
    0 => [
        'intID' => 3,
        "intVolumeType" => 1,
        "intVolume" => 10,
        "totalVolumes" => 10,
        "intTrack" => 10,
        "intTrackType" => 2,
        "totalTracks" => 10,
    ],
    1 => [
        "intID" => 4,
        "intVolumeType" => 2,
        "intVolume" => 100,
        "totalVolumes" => 200,
        "intTrack" => 111,
        "intTrackType" => 3,
        "totalTracks" => 222,
    ]
);
/*echo "<pre>";
print_r( $a );
echo "</pre>";
*/
// you have to do it manually
$volume = "";
$track = "";
foreach ( $a as $item ) {
    // preparing for volumes types
    $volume .= "intVolumeType = " . $item['intVolumeType'] . "<br/>";
    $volume .= "TotalVolumes = " . $item['totalVolumes'] . "<br/>";
    // you can add other variables too
    $volume .= "<br/>";
    // preparing for track types
    $track .= "intTrackType = " . $item['intTrackType'] . "<br/>";
    $track .= "TotalTracks = " . $item['totalTracks'] . "<br/>";
    // you can add other variables too  
    $track .= "<br/>";
}
echo $volume;
echo "===================<br/>";
echo $track;
?>
```